Specifying Color of Columns in MS Access Histogram Chart
I have a dynamic histogram (column chart) using the Modern Chart object in Access that functions just fine. However, the interior color of the columns are diffierent with each series selection by the user using the combo box at the top right of the form.(see figures below).
Figure 1.
Figure 2.
From my research, there are significant limitations to what I can control using formatting options available in VBA for Access. Microsoft's Support site lists a property for Chart objects called ChartSeries, which in turn, has a FillColor property. The syntax for use is:
*expressions*.ChartSeries.FillColor where expression represents a Chart object. When I attempt to use those properties, I get "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support the property or method." for the statement .ChartSeries.FillColor = lngBlue.  My code is below.
Private Sub cbo_ShipType_Change()

    Dim strSQL As String, cht As Chart, lngBlack As Long, lngBlue As Long
    
    lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    lngBlue = RGB(0, 0, 256)
    
    Set cht = Me.cht_ShipType
    strSQL = "SELECT tbl_ChartData.[YR], " & cbo_ShipType & " FROM tbl_ChartData"
    cht.RowSource = strSQL
    With cht
        .ChartTitle = cbo_ShipType & " Fleet Size"
        .PrimaryValuesAxisFontSize = 14
        .PrimaryValuesAxisFontColor = lngBlack
        .CategoryAxisFontSize = 12
        .CategoryAxisFontColor = lngBlack
        .ChartSeries.FillColor = lngBlue
        .Requery
    End With

End Sub

Does anyone know if or how I can adjust the colors of my data series columns?

MS documentation you read may be for MS Graph classic chart object, not Modern Charts. I have done this with MS Graph in Access.

Try cht.ChartSeriesCollection.Item("SumOfValue").FillColor = lngBlue where SumOfValue is your series name. A trick I use when dealing with the chart object is to set a breakpoint after the chart object has been set. Then, using your requirement, I would navigate through all the chart object properties looking for FillColor and try setting the value in the immediate window. FillColor can be found in a number of places but only one will be the one you want. I know it's clunky but it is quite effective.

Everything I read says it should work. However, might find this of interest https://www.devhut.net/ms-access-improved-charting/

Finally got it to work. My data has values "B" and "P" and these are the 2 series graphed. Me.chartname.ChartSeriesCollection.Item("B").FillColor = lngBlue. Using index numbers in places of data values fails.

Also, in my initial tests I was referencing alias series values displayed on chart instead of actual data. DOH!

If ship types are columns, that is not a normalized data structure. In a normalized structure the field name would not change - a filter for ship type would be applied. Chart RowSource could reference the combobox in WHERE clause and would not need to modify RowSource property. I have charts on reports set up with reference to textbox in order to filter. Series colors are assigned in design and do not change.

Well, rats! Learning more about Modern Charts. I cannot directly edit data source like I can RowSource property in old style chart. So my idea of filter in the RowSource SQL is not working out for Modern Chart. Guessing would still have to use VBA to modify SQL. And it's not liking SQL with JOIN. Another guess will have to build query object and use that as data source. So far, finding ModernCharts more annoyance than enhancement.

ShipType is a variable containing the column field name, For instance, "Destroyer", "Amphibious", and "Frigate" are ShipTypes and there is a column in tbl_ChartData for each of those headings. The first column in the table is "YR. Each row represents a record with the field YR containing the four-digit year for that record's data, followed by the various ShipType fields (e.g., "Destroyer") containing the number of Destroyers in the fleet during that year. . Users select a ShipType from a combo box on the form and that sets the column of data to be plotted for the time period previously set.

I tried using cht.ChartSeriesCollection.Item(cbo_ShipType).FillColor = lngBlue, but that doesn't do anything (no error, but doesn't change the color of the histogram bars either). Debugging shows that the variable cbo_ShipType in this line contains a string reflecting the selection in the cbo_ShipType form field on the graph. , e.g., "Amphibious".

Thanks! The Modern Chart object doesn't support the SeriesCollection object. Instead, it uses the ChartSeriesCollection object which has slightly different (and fewer) properties. After adding the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, I did at the following code based on your suggestion to fix my problem:
For j = 1 To cht.ChartSeriesCollection.Count - 1
    cht.ChartSeriesCollection(j).FillColor = vbBlue
Next j


Great. I still use Access 2016 and was not aware of the modern charts in 365.

Changing the color of histogram bars in Access 2016
First, in the VBA editor, go to Tools --> References, and add

Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library


Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library

This will enable the seriesCollection commands that will be used next:
Dim grphChart As Object
Dim j As Integer

Set grphChart = Me.cht_ShipType 

For j = 1 To grphChart.seriesCollection.Count

    With grphChart.seriesCollection(j)

        'Set the color
        .Interior.Color = vbBlue 'RGB(0, 0, 256)

        'Bar border color
        '.Border.Color = vbBlue 'RGB(0, 0, 256)
    End With

Next j

Further information in this Link 
